Calculating degrees of freedom with fixed symmetry
I stumbled upon a problem recently: I want to compute the number of degrees of freedom for a crystal/molecule if its symmetry is fixed.
I think what needs to be done is to compute the number of normal modes that have the a$_1$ symmetry.
For water for example that would be 8, (3 translations, 3 rotations, and 2 symmetric vibrations stretching and bending)
What would be nice to be able to do it quickly with python using a package like spglib... for any arbitrary system.
What I mean about "fixed symmetry": you run MD but the system is allowed to move  along directions that do not break the symmetry. e.g. water would stay c2v along the whole trajectory.

Could you define what you mean by "fixed symmetry"? If you were meaning having the totally symmetric irrep, there are only three totally symmetry degrees of freedom for water, which you can see from the reducible representation

I edited the question, I think you mean 2 modes (the a1 modes)?
